# Which architectures have modulo- / non-modulo-shifting?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture, bit-shift

When you shift a value on x86 with a variable shift count (in CL) the shift count is taken modulo the bit size of the destination operand. But is there an architecture which hasn't this kind of modulo-operation, i.e. if I shift further than there are bits in the operands the operand becomes zero (if I shift non-signed) ?

Comment: Older NVIDIA GPU architectures had dedicated left shift and right shift instructions that clamp the shift count to 0...32. Newer NVIDIA GPU architectures provide a unified funnel shift instruction with modifiers that allows one to select either clamping of the shift amount (shift count 0...32) or wrapping (shift count 0...31), e.g. `shf.l.clamp.b32` and `shf.r.wrap.b32`.

Answer (score 1):

x86-64 scalar shifts are mod-32 for 8 and 16-bit operand-size.  Only 32 and 64-bit shifts are modulo the operand-size.  (Modulo at all wasn't present in 8086, so being able to shift out all the bits in a 16-bit register was [perhaps a relevant backwards-compat issue for 186](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745808/why-any-modern-x86-masks-shift-count-to-the-5-low-bits-in-cl/61779201#61779201).  But for new extensions like 386 and amd64, there was no compat question so they could just define the semantics in a way that allowed a narrower barrel shifter with no extra condition.)

As Alex mentions, x86 SIMD shifts saturate the shift count, shifting out all the bits when >= element size.  For example, [`pslld xmm0, xmm1`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psllw:pslld:psllq) (And yes, they look at the full width of the low element of the source, not just the low byte.)

---

**ARM** uses all the bits [**in the low byte** of the shift-count](https://david.wragg.org/blog/2012/11/shift-instructions.html) register for variable-count shifts.  i.e. [modulo reduced to 0..255, then saturated to 0..32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330282/what-happens-when-you-bit-shift-beyond-the-end-of-a-variable#comment4707074_4330321).  (Fun fact: for immediate shifts, [it is possible to encode LSR by 1..32, but only LSL by 0..31](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66487890/why-different-ranges-of-permitted-shift-values-for-arm-lsl-vs-lsr))

IDK what other ISAs do; there might be some that are like x86 SIMD shifts.

Comment: The "low byte" behavior is for ARM32.  It appears from the manual that ARM64 switched to "mod 32 / 64" like x86.  Haven't tested it, though.  Kind of weird - is there anybody in the world who actually *wants* the masking behavior?  And wouldn't saturation only require like three more gates?  (If any of bits 6-63 is set then return 0.)

Comment: @NateEldredge: The only advantage I know of to masking is that it makes it easy to write UB-free C that matches the asm behaviour for any input.  e.g. `x << (n&31)` can optimize to just an `shlx`.  Relevant for expressing rotates where the opposite-direction shift would be out of range without masking, although on ISAs that actually have rotates that can all optimize away.  [Best practices for circular shift (rotate) operations in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776508)

Comment: Also interestingly, it looks like ARM64's SIMD shifts (`USHL` and friends) are back to the ARM32 behavior, where the low byte is used and shifts larger than word size yield zero.  As well as a form `USHLQ` that is truly saturating, where if you shift a 1 bit off the left end (i.e. the "multiplication" overflowed), you get the maximum unsigned integer value (all 1 bits).

Answer (score 0):

x86 has non-modulo shifts as well, if you consider MMX/SSE2/AVX2 `psrlq`, `psllw`, etc